# Replace column value if they starts with/match a string for pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column in my dataframe `prices_df` as `thumbnail_url`.

```
    zipcode thumbnail_url
0   11201   https://a0.muscache.com/im/pictures/6d7cbbf7-c...
1   10019   0
2   10027   https://a0.muscache.com/im/pictures/6fae5362-9...
3   94117   https://a0.muscache.com/im/pictures/72208dad-9...
4   20009   0
5   94131   https://a0.muscache.com/im/pictures/82509143-4...
```

I need to **replace** all **values** where the **row** contains `https://` or lets say contains `.com` with numeric value 1.

```
zipcode thumbnail_url
0   11201   1
1   10019   0
2   10027   1
```

Tried this

```
img_Uploaded = prices_df['thumbnail_url'].str.contains("http") == True
prices_df.replace(to_replace=prices_df[img_Uploaded],value=1,inplace=True)
```

My dataframe is of shape `(74111, 2)`

This line of code takes too much time and my system froze.
Can someone suggest a better vectorized operation and explain it.

**My issue is resolved** **but** I am curious **what was wrong with my code**? Apart from the fact that it did not optimized using vectorized operations? It should still run right? Or THAT is the reason why it froze and did not run whereas the codes suggested below ran in seconds

Comment: with *replace all values* you mean values in all columns?

Comment: Could you give a reproducible definition of the pandas dataframe for debugging.

Comment: No that specific column value. So in this case only elements starting with 'https' replaced as 1 and rest all the values of row (zipcode) is as is.

Comment: ```df.loc[('https:' in df['thumbnail_url]), 'thumbnail_url'] = 1``` (untested code, since you didn't provide reproducible sample.)

Comment: `df['zipcode'] = np.where(df['thumbnail_url'].str.contains('https|\.com'), 1, df['zipcode'])`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [apply()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) function to accomplish this:

```
prices_df.thumbnail_url = prices_df.thumbnail_url.apply(lambda url: 1 if 'http' in str(url) else url)
```

Comment: Getting error `'str' object has no attribute 'contains'`

Comment: Oops, I always forget my Python string methods. I edited the original answer, give that a try.

Comment: `TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable`

Comment: Edited again, casting url as a string.

Comment: Works now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use lambda expression

```
prices[['thumbnail_url']] = prices[['thumbnail_url']].apply(lambda x: 1 if 'https://' in str(x) else 0)
```

> They are a shorthand to create anonymous functions; the expression lambda parameters: expression yields a function object. The unnamed object behaves like a function object defined with

here`s [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda)

Comment: Replaced all as `NaN`.